# Get null when calling getSystemService("CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE")

Tags: android, infrared

I'm  trying to build a very simple Remote App for my TV.
After some research I found the `ConsumerIrManagerClass`, but when I call `this.getSystemService("CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE");` I get `null`...

The mobile is a Samsung Galaxy S4 so it has an IR Sensor...

Here's the code of my method:

```
public void btnOnOff_Click(View view) {
    String command = "0000 0073 0000 000c 0020 0020 0020 0020 0040 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0020 0040 0020 0020 0040 0020 0020 0cbf";
    irManager = (ConsumerIrManager) this.getSystemService("CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE");
    irManager.transmit(36000, hexToDec(command));
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE instead of a hard coded string.  You may be using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE) constant as parameter.

It's value is **`"consumer_ir"`**, not `"CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE"`.

Answer (score 0):

Also to be clear: it is an IR emitter, not a sensor.  The sensor is on the equipment you are controlling.

Chances are if you are doing:
Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE
and you get NULL your phone does not support this feature.  Try a free IR app in the Play store first to see if that works.